# HTML & CSS: Adjust background rectangle on text so it does not span entire webpage

Tags: html, css, text, background, element

I have the following code in the body section of my HTML index file.

```
<div class="titleMessage">

    <div class="heading">

        <p class="main">NAME HERE</p>
        <p class="sub">Software Engineer</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my CSS code:

```
.titleMessage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -125px;
}


.titleMessage .heading p{
    color:  #080808;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    background: #F5F5F5; 
    background-size: contain;
}

.titleMessage .heading .main{
    font-size: 50px; 
}


.titleMessage .heading .sub{
    font-size: 23px; 
}
```

Webpage:

[image]
The resulting webpage looks strange. Specifically, I want the background color on my text which is set to `#F5F5F5` to not stretch across the entire screen.

In fact, I only want the size of the background rectangle behind text to be a little bigger than the size of the actual text.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `span` tags around those texts and apply the `background` only to that span (spans are inline elements, which is why they won't stretch across the available width). Additionally (as shown below) you can add some `padding` to have more control over how much the background will extend:

```css
.titleMessage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -125px;
}


.titleMessage .heading p{
    color:  #080808;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
}
.titleMessage .heading p span{
    background: #F5F5F5; 
    padding: 6px 12px 0;
}
.titleMessage .heading .main{
    font-size: 50px; 
}


.titleMessage .heading .sub{
    font-size: 23px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="titleMessage">

    <div class="heading">

        <p class="main"><span>NAME HERE</span></p>
        <p class="sub"><span>Software Engineer</span></p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I make some changes to your CSS :

```
.titleMessage {
  margin-top:10rem;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}


.heading p{
    color:  #080808;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    background: #F5F5F5; 
}

.titleMessage .heading .main{
    font-size: 50px; 
}


.titleMessage .heading .sub{
    font-size: 23px; 
}
```